# How can I get mod from python?

Tags: python, statistics, mode

```
test = list(raws)
set(test)
SB = max(set(test), key=test.count)

print("Mode: ",[SB])
```

I can only get one mode from this. However, I count my file, it should have two modes. I really don't have any idea. What should I do?

Comment: `set` will discard duplicates because they hash to the same key

Comment: 1) what ti7 said 2) your title did you mean "mode" not "mod"? 3) what is the second line doing? 4) why are you wrapping SB in [] during print? 5) why are you using sets at all? I think your code is correct without the set casts (and probably without the list cast too, though impossible to know)

Comment: also, probably not what you need if you're just starting python, but scipy.stats.mode does this for you

Comment: Use a list comprehension to gather all the elements in test that have the same count as the one mode you found.